# Search in NSMutableDictionary only with partial key

Tags: objective-c, search

I want to know if there is a possibility to search in an `NSMutableDictionary` with a partial key.

For Eg.: Let `key` be `2345` and `partialkey` can be `2` or `23` or `234`,etc

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `allKeys` method to get an array of all the keys and then filter them based on your partial key.

Comment: Or you can iterate through the keys with [keyEnumerator](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/keyEnumerator) and examine each in turn.

Comment: Not for anything later than 10.5 - there are more efficient ways of doing it.

Comment: Fast enumeration on the returned array - or using a block to repeatedly filter the array of keys depending on the input.